# Unable to sudo apt-get update for Ubuntu (Windows subsystem for Linux)

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Above is the error I receive every time I attempt to update Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu from the microsoft store, it's the one with no version listed in the title.
Since I can't update, I am also unable to get gcc, make, etc as well. I receive the same error each time.

Any tips or advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE (May 4 2021):
The solution is to type

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

into the terminal. It adds a nameserver (specifically Google's server) so everything can connect and update. Immediately after doing this I was able to successfully update the files and download gcc, make, and other files using sudo apt -get.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes i am connected to the internet

Comment: Try running the command again.

Comment: I've done this several times and tried a few different ways of running the command. it doesn't want to connect and update for some reason

Comment: Thanks. Quick fix for an issue that seems to be cropping up a lot these days.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VPN
The solution is to disable the wsl adapter before connect to the vpn

1- Disconnect and close client vpn
2- launch your wsl
3- ping google: it should be work
4- In a PowerShell, disable wsl adapter :

```
netsh interface set interface "vEthernet (WSL)" disable
```

5- Connect to your VPN client
6- Enable the wsl adapter

```
netsh interface set interface "vEthernet (WSL)" enable
```

7- ping google : it should work and you can do your command apt